# Is there a way I can make null variables automatically fail fast in my code base unless they're marked with `@Nullable`?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guice, nullable

By chance I bumped into this article: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable

> To eliminate NullPointerExceptions in your codebase, you must be disciplined about null references. We've been successful at this by following and enforcing a simple rule: *Every parameter is non-null unless explicitly specified.*

Is this done with shear discipline, or is it automated in some way?  Unfortunately, it seems like it's the former?  Is there a way I can make null variables **automatically** fail fast in my code base unless they're marked with `@Nullable`?

Comment: related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/168395/check-parameters-annotated-with-nonnull-for-null

Comment: Guava uses a [NullPointerTester](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/NullPointerTester.java) to reflectively call every method with nulls and verify that they throw NPE if they aren't annotated @Nullable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman is this internal code that I shouldn't be using in my projects?

Comment: It's part of Guava's testing library; I don't think it has compatibility guarantees but I'm fairly certain it's what Guice uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is automated, not done with sheer discipline.

As Louis Wasserman noted, Google's testing code has special treatment for parameters that are marked as `@Nullable`.

It can be good to fail fast during testing or at run time, but it's even better to learn about problems at compile time or to get a compile-time guarantee that no errors will occur at run time.

Google previously used [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to help find null pointer exceptions at compile time, but Google has now largely abandoned FindBugs because of the difficulty of integrating it with the Google build system.

Dozens of projects at Google use the [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org/)'s [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) to find null pointer errors statically at compile time.  The Nullness Checker has [found errors](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/pubs/pluggable-checkers-icse2011.pdf) in the Google Collections library, which is part of Guava.

My source for this information is friends who work on programming tools at Google.

Comment: "Google previously used FindBugs to help find null pointer exceptions at compile time, but Google has now largely abandoned FindBugs because of the difficulty of integrating it with the Google build system." How do you use findbugs at compile time?  Isn't it static analysis?

Comment: Every compile-time analysis is a static analysis.  "Static analysis" means that the analysis is done without running the code.  FindBugs actually works on .class files (but without running the code, so it's still a static analysis).  A standard way of using FindBugs is to compile the code and then immediately run FindBugs on it.  So FindBugs isn't run within the compiler, but it's part of the compilation process as viewed by the programmer.

Comment: It's not important to the big picture.  I just disagree with your choice of the phrase "at compile time".  Technically it was between compile time and run time.  At least that's my understanding.

Comment: Sure, you can view it that way if you want.  In any event, there is no conflict betweeen "at compile time" and "static analysis".  For example, type-checking is a static analysis that occurs at compile time.